# chain of subtypings - just a syntax limitation?

Tags: scala, polymorphism

This question has likely been already been asked.

Why is this not supported?

```
class A;
class B[T];
class MyClass[T <: B[U <: A]];
```

I could have shrugged this off as some limitation of the language syntax but now I am afraid there is a somewhat "deeper" explanation.

```
class A;
class B[T];
class MyClass[U <: A, T <: B[U]];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nested type bounds like this *are* supported. If you don't want `U` to be a parameter of `MyClass`, you can write

```
class MyClass[T <: B[_ <: A]]

class C extends A
class D extends B[C]

def x: MyClass[D] = ??? // compiles
def y: MyClass[B[C]] = ??? // compiles
def z: MyClass[B[String]] = ??? // doesn't compile because `String` is not a subtype of `A`
```

Does this correspond to what you want?